# rails 4: URL Link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a web app which allows them to add a website url e.g www.google.com in a listings form
so on the show page anyone can click on this and go the webpage www.google.com

Tried a few things link_to and  etc but cannot seem to get it to work correctly

listings.form

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Tell Us About Your Business 25-30 chars max" %>
    <%= f.text_area :about, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Company Website" %>
    <%= f.text_field :url , class: "form-control", placeholder: "E.g www.google.com"  %>
  </div>
```

show.html.erb

```
 <div class="blog-header">
        <h1 class="blog-title"><%= @listing.job %></h1>
        <p class="lead blog-description"><b>Posted on</b> <%= @listing.created_at.strftime("%B %-d, %Y") %></p>
        <h4><%= @listing.company %></h4>
        <h4><%= @listing.location %></h4>
        ***<h4><%= link_to @listing.url %></h4>*** 
      </div>
```

so at the moment it creates a link but does not go to the webpage.

**updated code**

```
<div class="blog-header">
        <h1 class="blog-title"><%= @listing.job %></h1>
        <p class="lead blog-description"><b>Posted on</b> <%= @listing.created_at.strftime("%B %-d, %Y") %></p>
        <h4><%= @listing.company %></h4>
        <h4><%= @listing.location %></h4>
        <h4><%= link_to @listing.url, @listing.url %></h4> 
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no it creates a link but is not active

Comment: What do you mean `it is not active`?

Comment: so it creates a link but when you click on the link nothing happens it shows the url of the page not the url of the website e.g google.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass two arguments to `link_to`

```
<%= link_to @listing.url, @listing.url %>
```

The first argument is the name of the link to display, if you don't set a second argument then rails will link to the current page

Comment: passed two arguments as suggested but when i try again it links to the current page

Comment: Passing a single argument works fine as long as it's a URL. i.e.: `link_to "http://google.com"`.

Comment: getting confused now :) when the user lists his/her website e.g google.com in the form i then want to show it as an active link once they have submitted the form tried add http in the form but still gives me a link that sends to to the listings page not the link google.com

Comment: hi got this working now by adding the 2 arugments and using the http , thanks

Comment: @JamesMason, no it doesn't it requires 2 arguments.  It might have worked in earlier versions of rails.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work fine, as long as you require tour users to type http:// or https:// before all of their URLs. Without that, the browser will interpret whatever you enter as a relative URL.

Comment: ok i understand at the moment i have placeholder text like this -> placeholder: "E.g www.google.com"  %> I should change this to "E.g(http://google.com